# Ionic 3 image broken on production

Tags: ionic3

I have this code working locally:

```
  background-image: url('/assets/images/board.png');
```

But not on production:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mind.your.maths&hl=en_GB
The image doesn't display at all. It looks like the problem is only with the css, not facing any issue with html images on same folder

Comment: Have you tried `background-image: url('assets/images/board.png');` instead of `background-image: url('/assets/images/board.png');` ?

Comment: yes, and doesn't work. With html works using /assets and assets either way

Comment: Ok, I don't know why but it has to be like: ../assets/images/board.png on css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ionic project sass files you have to reference the assets relative to parent directory.  Has to do with how the app is packaged on the device.

`background-image: url('../assets/images/board.png');`

Answer (score 0):

I also facing same problem. Finally I found solution. Ionic application is single page application so everything is render in index.html page.

I have given src path base on index.html page, now it is working.

Example :

Relative path from any html file :

```
./assets/yourpath
```

Relative path from any css file :

```
../assets/yourpath
```

Comment: Sorry but I did not understand what you did on `index.html`, as I am facing the same problem here I would like to ask if you can show me what you did.

Comment: @devnosaur i did nothing in inext.html. when you giving image or any file reference, you have to give relative path from index.html because every page render in index.html

Comment: @devnosaur check answer i added example